# Amazon SNS topic,subscription and push notifications management from Android,iOS device

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am a newbie to AWS and am exploring it for a mobile application targeted for Android and iOS platforms.One of my application's requirement is to provide push notifications wherein users subscribe to particular topic(s) and then get notifications for those topics.I had gone through Amazon SNS which intends to do exactly the same. Moreover, I have also tested sending push notifications to registered devices from AWS console. This works like a charm.

However,this is a manual process and I want this to be dynamic but without using an intermediate server. Rather I want to do this from the device(s) themselves using AWS Android, iOS SDKs. Thus I have following queries-

1. Can the **Topics** for SNS push notifications be created from within app?
2. Can **Subscriptions** to a particular topic be managed from the app itself?
3. Most importantly can push messages be **published** from devices to all subscribed devices of that topic?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You shouldn't think about performing push notifications or creating topics as part of the SNS API. You need to create an interface to create notifications and topics which talks to your remote server and performs these actions saving the data in a Datastore. Then the server (Provider) should handle push notifications through SNS on various topics, based on management of topics and it's subscribers. Any reason why you do not want to go through this standard route?

Comment: Thanks @Priyeshj for your reply!
Actually,so far in my application I haven't had the need for an intermediate server thanks to really convenient AWS SDK for Android and iOS & also because the functionality till now has been quite simple.So I was just wondering if I could skip the need for server altogether with SNS also, for managing push notifications and do it from my Android & iOS apps only.Turns out that neither is this recommended nor feasible.Will now act accordingly. Thanks again!!

Comment: In the AWSSNS class there's a method that allows you to create a topic, and if a topic already exists, it just returns the ARN for that topic rather than creating a new one. As for your third point, @Priyeshj explained how that should work, as for subs to a topic, I'm still working that out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on AWS SNS on iOS, and the answer to your questions are :

1. YES, topics can be created from within the app itself
2. YES, Subscriptions can be managed from the app also
3. YES, Push messages can be published from devices to all subscribed devices of a topic.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. And let me know if sample codes are needed.

Thank you.

Comment: In general, we do not recommend giving the mobile devices the permissions to create topics. If your use case allows it, you should create them from the AWS Management Console for security purposes.

By default, SNS offers 10 million subscriptions per topic, and 100,000 topics per account. If you need a higher limit, you need to contact [AWS Support](http://aws.amazon.com/support).

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda is this still the general recommendation from aws?  do you know where I can find this in official documentation?   the api reference does not mention this.

Comment: Hi tyegah123, yes, sample codes are needed please, for sending publishing to a topic, sending notification directly to an endpointAPN. Thanks.